# How do I setup a PC to allow a link local device on one side see the network but not the other way

Tags: networking

I am trying to use two Network cards to run a production test on a network-able measurement device.

On the first network card is the company network.
On the second network card is the measurement device. 
The measurement device has two addresses by default. One meant for link local the other is automatically set to DHCP. I don't want any other PC to see the the measurement device. BI would like to use the default link local address only on the PC it is connected to. I have multiple measurement devices connected using link local to the PC they share a bench with. But I want the measurement device to have access to the company file server for firmware updates.

Is this possible?

Should I be using a bridge? Or maybe ICS?

Is my question clear?

Comment: You'll probably want a firewall device if you use this in production (to isolate it from the company network). My company does this for our plant verses office networks. ICS may work for it, you just have to set the rules properly. Essentially you want no rules, though, as you only "established" connections from the measuring device to the network to be allowed back through the other way, but block everything else coming at it. If you do a software bridge, everyone will have access to that device.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the difference between the 2 features. I will play with the ICS settings. I should be able to stumble on the correct settings. I will post them when I think I have it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The safest thing to do is what you are doing now (assuming you are sure nothing would be "forwarding" traffic between the network cards and the PC is itself secure), but copy the firmware updates to your system (the other side of the "link local" network that the PC and instruments are on).  That way the device can get its updates from the PC and has no need to connect to the network at all.

Other than that, you'll need to connect the device to the network, but put a very restrictive firewall in front of it.  You could also leverage the NAT facilites of a consumer router or Windows' Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) features.

If the PC is a Windows system, you could share your PC's internet connection with ICS, and then connect the DHCP-enabled interface of the instrument to your PC.  ICS uses NAT, so no unsolicitied communications could reach the instruments, yet the instrumentss can reach outside.  Similar setups with Linux are possible, or you could get a consumer router, setup NAT, and put it between your instrument and the company network.

Comment: I will try the ICS settings. I have already created scripts that work with the file server to automate the firmware uploads. I don't want to rewrite that and require local copies of the files on each production PC. . Updates to come.

Comment: So I enabled ICS on a windows 7 PC and enabled ftp and http. I then added the link local address to my second NIC. This allows me to control the measurement device via an SSH connection(I forgot to specify the need for SSH). I was able to acquire the firmware upgrade files and no other device on the network saw the measure device. Now I need to try it on the an XP machine.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? This is completely dependent on OS.

[This site](http://www.subhashdasyam.com/2011/06/how-to-hide-your-computer-in-lanlocal.html) says to do this on windows:

1. Open the command prompt [as admin](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/)

2. Type `C:\Documents and Settings\Imports.system>net config server /hidden:yes`

Comment: The measurement devices run linux. The PCs in the lab run both Win7 an WinXP.

Comment: What benefit is there to setting the server hidden feature to Yes.

Comment: Let me preface this with I am a novice. What benefit is there to setting the server hidden feature to Yes. Will this make the PC hidden or the measurement device or both?

Comment: Setting it to hidden, will make it so the PC can see other devices, but no other devices will be able to see the PC. I don't know how to do it on linux.

Comment: I say follow [this guid](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26779/the-best-way-to-hide-my-computer-on-a-network): `iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` then 
`iptables -p INPUT DROP`. Which should block all incoming traffic. It might break other things, but will probably do what you want it to.